# What is the value of ABAP constants with prefix "%_"?

Tags: constants, abap

We are writing a tool in Java to analyze ABAP programs.  The code is extracted and given to us as text, so we do not have direct access to the ABAP system. One task is to resolve the value of constants.  We now discovered constants whose name starts with `%_`.  For example, a definition in a class pool include `CL_ABAP_CHAR_UTILITIES========CU` is

> constants HORIZONTAL_TAB type ABAP_CHAR1 value %_HORIZONTAL_TAB.

which transitively defines the value of constant `HORIZONTAL_TAB` via another constant whose name has the prefix `%_`.

Where are these constants with `%_` prefix defined? What is their value? We guess, they are system dependent. Is there an official document describing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some internal (pseudo-)constants that you will simply have to accept as a given. Stuff beginning with `%_` is usually reserved for ABAP internal use and is hardly ever documented.

Comment: Would it be an option to extract these constant values along with the ABAP code of a system? That's one of the solutions we discuss.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these constants are not provided by ABAP statements but are built into the kernel. They are available in any program, and they are not part of `<REPINI>`, `<SYSINI>`, `<SYSSEL>` or or one of the other default includes that are silently included by the system.